На ПК приложение на Flask отрабатывает, а на сервере pythonenywhere всё работает кроме экспорта csv-файла на ПК. Почему?
это Python-файл:
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_file
import requests
import csv
import os
import logging
import json
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
app = Flask(__name__)


# Функция для поиска вакансий
def search_vacancies(keyword):
    BASE_URL = "https://api.hh.ru/vacancies"
    vacancies_found = []  # Список для хранения найденных вакансий
    per_page = 100
    page = 0

    while True:
        params = {
            'text': keyword,
            'page': page,
            'per_page': per_page,
            'only_with_salary': True  # Только вакансии с зарплатой
        }

        response = requests.get(BASE_URL, params=params)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print("Ошибка при обращении к API")
            break

        lan = response.json()

        if not lan['items']:
            break

        for item in lan['items']:
            # vacancy_name = item['name']
            vacancy_name = item['name'].lower()  # Приводим название вакансии к нижнему регистру для сравнения
            # Проверяем, содержит ли название вакансии ключевое слово
            if keyword in vacancy_name:
                salary_from = item['salary']['from'] if item['salary'] else None
                salary_to = item['salary']['to'] if item['salary'] else None
                currency = item['salary']['currency'] if item['salary'] else None
                city = item['area']['name'] if 'area' in item else None
                link = item['alternate_url'] if 'alternate_url' in item else None
                discription = item['snippet']['responsibility'] if 'snippet' in item else None

                vacancies_found.append({
                    'name': vacancy_name,
                    'salary_from': salary_from,
                    'salary_to': salary_to,
                    'currency': currency,
                    'city': city,
                    'link': link,
                    'discription': discription
                })

        page += 1

    return vacancies_found


# Функция для сохранения вакансий в CSV
def save_to_csv(vacancies, filename='vacancies.csv'):
    # Если имя файла не передано, создаем его на основе ключевого слова
    keys = vacancies[0].keys()
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-16') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=keys)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(vacancies)
    return filename  # Возвращаем имя файла


@app.route('/download')
def download_file():
    return send_file('vacancies.csv', as_attachment=True)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        keyword = request.form['keyword']
        vacancies = search_vacancies(keyword)
        if vacancies:
            filename = save_to_csv(vacancies)
            return render_template('index.html', vacancies=vacancies, filename=filename, download=True)
        else:
            return render_template('index.html', message='Нет найденных вакансий')
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)    

это html-файл:
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Парсер вакансий</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Парсер вакансий</h1>
<form method="POST">
    <label for="keyword">Введите вакансию для поиска:</label>
    <input type="text" id="keyword" style="margin-left: -2%;" name="keyword" required>
    <button type="submit">Искать</button>
</form>
{% if vacancies %}
    <h2>Найденные вакансии: </h2>
    {% if download %}
        <a href="/download" class="form-control">Скачать вакансии в CSV</a>
    {% endif %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Название</th>
            <th>Зарплата от</th>
            <th>Зарплата до</th>
            <th>Валюта</th>
            <th>Город</th>
            <th>Описание</th>
            <th>Ссылка</th>
        </tr>
        {% for vacancy in vacancies %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ vacancy.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ vacancy.salary_from }}</td>
                <td>{{ vacancy.salary_to }}</td>
                <td>{{ vacancy.currency }}</td>
                <td>{{ vacancy.city }}</td>
                <td>{{ vacancy.discription }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ vacancy.link }}" class="vacancy-link">{{ vacancy.link }}</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% elif message %}
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
{% endif %}
{% if download %}
    <a href="/download" class="form-control">Скачать вакансии в CSV</a>
{% endif %}
</table>
</body>
</html>

Это парсер вакансий hh.ru по API. На ПК всё отрабатывает нормально, загружаю на сервер pythonenywhere всё работает кроме скачивания csv-файла на ПК. Выдаёт такую ошибку:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

И ещё:

Could not edit /home/gloone/vacancies.csv. PythonAnywhere's editor only recognises ASCII or UTF8-encoded text

Если кто знает подскажите в чём ошибка?
Ссылка на приложение:  https://gloone.pythonanywhere.com/

Ну про кодировку во втором случае пишет, сразу смотрим в какой кодировке csv сохраняете - в utf-16 зачем-то. Пробуйте utf-8.

менял кодировку - пишет то же самое

Смотрите логи приложения самого
